# Customize JsonSchemaValidation Error Messages

Tags: c#, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am using a Json Schema to validate a json Object. I am getting the error messages correctly. But it looks more of a developer friendly error message. Is there any way to customize the error message so that I can make it more user friendly. I have looked into many forums where i couldnt get a solution.

Below is the code i used:

```
        string Json = @"{'Sheet1':[{'Location':'#$','First Name':11,'Last Name':'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA','Amount':'A','Date of Birth':'8522/85/25'}]}";
        string JSONSchemaValidator = @"{'$schema':'http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#','title':'JSON Validation Schema','type':'object','additionalProperties':true,'properties':{'Sheet1':{'type':'array','items':{'type':'object','additionalProperties':true,'properties':{'Location':{'type':['number','string','null'],'pattern':'^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\s]+$','maxLength':15},'First Name':{'type':['string','null'],'maxLength':20,'pattern':'^[a-zA-Z\\-\\s]+$'},'Last Name':{'type':['string','null'],'maxLength':10,'pattern':'^[a-zA-Z\\-\\s]+$'},'Amount':{'type':['number','null'],'minimum':-999999999.99,'maximum':999999999.99,'exclusiveMaximum':true,'multipleOf':0.01},'Date of Birth':{'type':['string','null'],'format':'date-time'}}}}}}";
        JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(JSONSchemaValidator);
        JObject person = JObject.Parse(Json);
        IList<string> iJSONSchemaValidatorErrorList;
        bool valid = person.IsValid(schema, out iJSONSchemaValidatorErrorList);

        if (iJSONSchemaValidatorErrorList != null && iJSONSchemaValidatorErrorList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string error in iJSONSchemaValidatorErrorList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(error);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Below are the error messages I get :

```
1. String '#$' does not match regex pattern '^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$'. Path 'Sheet1[0].Location', line 1, position 27.
2. Invalid type. Expected String, Null but got Integer. Path 'Sheet1[0]['First Name']', line 1, position 43.
3. String 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA' exceeds maximum length of 10. Path 'Sheet1[0]['Last Name']', line 1, position 87.
4. Invalid type. Expected Number, Null but got String. Path 'Sheet1[0].Amount', line 1, position 100.
5. String '8522/85/25' does not validate against format 'date-time'. Path 'Sheet1[0]['Date of Birth']', line 1, position 129.
```

I am looking for something like :

```
 1. 'Location' in Column 1 of Sheet1 should be alphanumeric.
 2. 'Name' in Column 1 of Sheet1 should only contain alphabets.
 3. 'Last Name' in column 1 exceeds maximum length of 10.
 4. 'Amount' in column 1 should contain only numbers.
 5. 'Date of Birth' in column 1 is not a valid date.
```

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue as this. Will post here if I find a solution. For the time being, I've written my own classes, customised to the particular schema I'm working with, which perform particular checks on the error data returned by Json-Schema-Validator and return more user-friendly versions of the error messages. I'm considering starting to work on my own possibly open-source validation library for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

In my case, I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema` (yes, I paid for a license!) was generating a `JSchema` from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` attributes - and I saw it was generating a correct `JSchema`, but the validation error messages weren't using the `ErrorMessage` properties on the attributes at all.

## Part 1 : Background:

It turns out that's because `JSchemaGenerator` generates `JSchema` rules using only a subset of Data-Annotation attribute properties - and it ignores the `ErrorMessage` property.

The set of attribute properties it does use [are documented on the "Generating schemas" page](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/GeneratingSchemas.htm):

```
JSchema member            Data Annotation attribute class        Attribute properties used
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
required                  [Required]                             
minLength                 [StringLength]                         .MinimumLength
maxLength                 [StringLength]                         .MaximumLength
minLength                 [MinLength]                            .Length
maxLength                 [MaxLength]                            .Length
minItems                  [MinLength]                            .Length
maxItems                  [MaxLength]                            .Length
pattern                   [RegularExpression]                    .Pattern
enum                      [EnumDataType]                         .EnumType
format                    [DataType]                             .DataType
format                    [Url]
format                    [Phone]
format                    [EmailAddress]
minimum                   [Range]                                .Minimum
maximum                   [Range]                                .Maximum
```

So armed with this knowledge, we can attempt to get the customized validation message from the attributes' `ErrorMessage` property by reflecting the type being deserialized and looking for matching data-annotation attributes on the appropriate `PropertyInfo` members.

---

## Part 2: `ValidationError`

The validation errors from `JSchemaValidatingReader` are exposed as `Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.ValidationError` objects, which contains:

- The `Path` property,  which we'll need to reverse from the target type's property names or any matching `[JsonProperty]` attributes.
- The `ErrorType` enum which we can use to determine which attribute types to look for.

---

## Part 3: Static JSON Property and Data Annotation cache

For performance reasons, we don't want to reflect-over each type and attribute every time, so this code below is a static-generic cache (make sure it's marked as `internal` to avoid violating CA1000).

```
internal static class JsonPropertiesCache<T>
{
    /// <summary>Case-sensitive.</summary>
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<String,JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes> AttributesByJsonPropertyName { get; } = CreateJsonPropertiesDictionary();

    private static Dictionary<String,JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes> CreateJsonPropertiesDictionary()
    {
        return typeof(T)
            .GetProperties( BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public )
            .Select( pi => ( ok: JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes.TryCreate( pi, out JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes attrs ), attrs ) )
            .Where( t => t.ok )
            .Select( t => t.attrs )
#if DEBUG
            .ToDictionary( attrs => attrs.Name ); // This will throw if there's a duplicate JSON property name.
#else
            .GroupBy( attrs => attrs.Name )
            .ToDictionary( grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.First() ); // This won't throw, but will only use attributes from the first match (whichever match that is).
#endif
    }
}

public class JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes
{
    public static Boolean TryCreate( PropertyInfo pi, out JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes attrs )
    {
        // Only create an instance if at least one DataAnnotation validation attribute is present:

        if( pi?.GetCustomAttributes<ValidationAttribute>()?.Any() ?? false )
        {
            attrs = new JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes( pi );
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            attrs = default;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes( PropertyInfo pi )
    {
        this.PropertyInfo      = pi ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof(pi) );
        this.JsonProperty      = pi.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>();

        this.Required          = pi.GetCustomAttribute<RequiredAttribute>();
        this.MinLength         = pi.GetCustomAttribute<MinLengthAttribute>();
        this.StringLength      = pi.GetCustomAttribute<StringLengthAttribute>();
        this.MaxLength         = pi.GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>();
        this.RegularExpression = pi.GetCustomAttribute<RegularExpressionAttribute>();
        this.Url               = pi.GetCustomAttribute<UrlAttribute>();
        this.Phone             = pi.GetCustomAttribute<PhoneAttribute>();
        this.Email             = pi.GetCustomAttribute<EmailAddressAttribute>();
        this.Range             = pi.GetCustomAttribute<RangeAttribute>();
        this.EnumDataType      = pi.GetCustomAttribute<EnumDataTypeAttribute>(); // NOTE: `EnumDataTypeAttribute` is a subclass of `DataTypeAttribute`.
        this.DataType          = pi.GetCustomAttribute<DataTypeAttribute>();
    }

    public PropertyInfo               PropertyInfo      { get; }
    public JsonPropertyAttribute      JsonProperty      { get; }
    public String                     Name              => this.JsonProperty?.PropertyName ?? this.PropertyInfo.Name; // TODO: Support custom NamingStrategies.

    public RequiredAttribute          Required          { get; }
    public MinLengthAttribute         MinLength         { get; }
    public StringLengthAttribute      StringLength      { get; }
    public MaxLengthAttribute         MaxLength         { get; }
    public RegularExpressionAttribute RegularExpression { get; }
    public UrlAttribute               Url               { get; }
    public PhoneAttribute             Phone             { get; }
    public EmailAddressAttribute      Email             { get; }
    public RangeAttribute             Range             { get; }
    public EnumDataTypeAttribute      EnumDataType      { get; }
    public DataTypeAttribute          DataType          { get; }

    public Boolean TryFormatValidationErrorMessage( ErrorType errorType, out String errorMessage )
    {
        switch( errorType )
        {
        case ErrorType.MaximumLength:

            errorMessage = this.MaxLength?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name ) ?? this.StringLength?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        case ErrorType.MinimumLength:

            errorMessage = this.MinLength?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name ) ?? this.StringLength?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        case ErrorType.Pattern:

            errorMessage = this.RegularExpression?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );
                
        case ErrorType.MaximumItems:
                
            errorMessage = this.MaxLength?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        case ErrorType.MinimumItems:
                
            errorMessage = this.MinLength?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        case ErrorType.Required:
                
            errorMessage = this.Required?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        case ErrorType.Enum:
                
            errorMessage = this.EnumDataType?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        case ErrorType.Format:

            // Same precedence order as used by Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.Infrastructure::GetFormat(JsonProperty):
                errorMessage = this.Url?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name ) ?? this.Phone?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name ) ?? this.Email?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name ) ?? this.DataType?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
                return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        case ErrorType.Maximum:
        case ErrorType.Minimum:
                
            errorMessage = this.Range?.FormatErrorMessage( this.Name );
            return !String.IsNullOrEmpty( errorMessage );

        default:
            errorMessage = default;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Part 4: Getting `ErrorMessage` from `SchemaValidationEventArgs`

So given your set of `SchemaValidationEventArgs`, getting the human-readable validation errors is a simple case of matching the type you're deserializing and using the dictionary above.

**Caveat**: This code does not currently support DTO class JSON properties that are classes themselves - but implementing that is rather straightforward and is an exercise for the reader.

```
private static Result<T> DeserializeAndValidate<T>( String body, JSchema schema )
{
    if( body == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(body));

    //

    List<SchemaValidationEventArgs> messages = new List<SchemaValidationEventArgs>();

    using( StringReader textReader = new StringReader( body ) )
    using( JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader( textReader ) )
    using( JSchemaValidatingReader validatingReader = new JSchemaValidatingReader( jsonTextReader ) )
    {
        validatingReader.Schema = schema;
        validatingReader.ValidationEventHandler += ( sender, eventArgs ) => messages.Add( eventArgs );

        //

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        T value = serializer.Deserialize<T>( validatingReader );
                
        if( messages.Count == 0 )
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            IReadOnlyDictionary<String,JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes> dict = JsonPropertiesCache<T>.AttributesByJsonPropertyName;

            return messages
                .Select( e => e.ValidationError )
                .Flatten( err => err.ChildErrors )
                .Select( err => ( err, ok: dict.TryGetValue( err.Path, out JsonPropertyDataAnnotationAttributes attr ), attr ) )
                .Select( t => t.ok && t.attr.TryFormatValidationErrorMessage( t.err.ErrorType, out String errorMessage ) ? errorMessage : t.err.Message )
                .StringJoin( separator: "\r\n" );
        }
```